Implement a method that takes takes 2 parameters and returns a hash with the amount of times a substring occurred in the string
I am currently learning Ruby through the odin project curriculum. This is the project description:
Implement a method #substrings that takes a word as the first argument and then an array of valid substrings (your dictionary) as the second argument. It should return a hash listing each substring (case insensitive) that was found in the original string and how many times it was found.
dictionary = ["below","down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part","partner","sit"]
# => ["below","down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part","partner","sit"]

substrings("below", dictionary)
# => { "below" => 1, "low" => 1 }

substrings("Howdy partner, sit down! How's it going?", dictionary)
#  => { "down" => 1, "go" => 1, "going" => 1, "how" => 2, "howdy" => 1, "it" => 2, "i" => 3, "own" => 1, "part" => 1, "partner" => 1, "sit" => 1 }

I first turned the string into an array so that each word is an array element. I looped through the dictionary and then looped through the string array to compare both words to see if it contained the substring from the dictionary. I checked for the substring using string[substring]. If that didn't return nil (meaning the string contained that substring from the dictionary, I would push it into my hash, creating anew key value pair.
def substrings(string, dictionary)
  result = Hash.new
  string_array = string.split" "

  dictionary.each do |dic_word|
    string_array.each do |string_word|
      string_word = string_word.downcase
      if string_word[dic_word] != nil
        if result.key?(dic_word)
          result[dic_word] += 1
        else
          result[dic_word] = 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
  result
end

The method works fine, my question is around time complexity and best practice in Ruby. Is there a way to make this more efficient? or maybe a way to make it look cleaner using other methods that would work better given this problem.
Any other constructive feedback around my code readability, variable names, etc would be greatly appreciated.

With your approach, substrings("going", ["g"]) will return {"g"=>1}, although "g" occurs twice.

Maybe checkout Enumerable#each_with_object, there are a lot of counting examples available on SO and elsewhere. Since this kind of falls into a "homework problem" and you already have a working process (sans what @Stefan pointed out), I'm going to abstain from answering but as a hint: we can boil your code down to 1-3 lines using this method, along with a Hash with a default value.

There is a dedicated subsite voor questions like this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

@Stefan thank you for pointing that out I didn't notice that

@engineersmnky Thanks for the tip. I want to get more comfortable using other methods other than #each so I'll give it a try. Cheers!

I found out the ruby has a #scan method that would improve performance and not require a new array
def substrings(string, dictionary)
  result = Hash.new
  string = string.downcase
  dictionary.each do |word|
    result[word] = string.scan(word).length unless string.scan(word).length == 0
  end
  result
end


Note that calling string.scan(word) twice will actually scan the string twice. You might want to assign the result to a variable.

Instead of double scanning you could go with something simpler like if string.include?(word).
